# Extracting date and other data from scraped items

Tags: python, algorithm, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm writing a Python code using lxml, urllib and csv to scrape speechs in [a Brazil government site](http://www2.planalto.gov.br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos/discursos-da-presidenta?b_start:int=0).

I was able to find the title and the link for each speech using XPath, but not the exact day, since there's no specific tag before for the date of the speech.

When I use the XPath `'//span[@class="summary-view-icon"]/text()`, the scraper brings back the day, the hour and the word "Página" (page, in portuguese). I know this Xpath is not right, but I don't know how to select only the day.

Even with this mistake, I was able to transform the **scraped** content in to a list and edit to delete everything but the days. The problem is that the final list, as you can see below, has some other characters that I can't delete.

There seems to be two solutions here: get the XPath right or edit out the other characters in the list. How can I do any of them?

['\n                                                18/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                21/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                21/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                22/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                22/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                22/12/2015\n                                            ', '\n                                                11/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                19/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                21/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                26/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                27/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                27/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                28/01/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                01/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                01/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                02/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                02/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                02/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                03/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                03/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                19/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                19/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                22/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                26/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                26/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                02/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                03/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                04/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                07/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                04/02/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                08/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                09/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                17/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                18/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                22/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                23/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                23/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                30/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                31/03/2016\n                                            ', '\n                                                01/04/2016\n                                            ']

Comment: Just strip the white spaces around `[d.strip() for d in ds]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the followin XPath to narrow down the result to only the dates :

```
//span[@class="summary-view-icon"][i/@class="icon-day"]/text()[normalize-space()]
```

The last bit of the above XPath (`text()[normalize-space()]`) returns only *non-empty* text nodes. From here, you still need to remove unnecessary whitespaces using `strip()` :

```
query = '//span[@class="summary-view-icon"][i/@class="icon-day"]/text()[normalize-space()]'
dates = root.xpath(query)
result = [date.strip() for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get you what you want:

```
items = response.xpath('//div[@id="content-core"]//div[contains(@class, "tileItem")]')
for item in items:
    date = item.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="summary-view-icon"][i[@class="icon-day"] ]//text()[normalize-space()])')
```

Using normalize-space twice will strip delete empty results + strip all whitespaces of the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You could strip all the newline characters / spaces from the elements in the list using `strip`:

```
new_list = [item.strip() for item in old_list]
```

**Edit**: You said you were able to transform the results into the list in your question in that case you could just strip the elements there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
dates = [re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', item, re.MULTILINE).group(0) for item in old_list]
```

Gives:

```
['18/12/2015', '21/12/2015', '21/12/2015', '22/12/2015', '22/12/2015',
'22/12/2015', '11/01/2016', '19/01/2016', '21/01/2016', '26/01/2016',
'27/01/2016', '27/01/2016', '28/01/2016', '01/02/2016', '01/02/2016',
'02/02/2016', '02/02/2016', '02/02/2016', '03/02/2016', '03/02/2016',
'19/02/2016', '19/02/2016', '22/02/2016', '26/02/2016', '26/02/2016',
'02/03/2016', '03/03/2016', '04/03/2016', '07/03/2016', '04/02/2016',
'08/03/2016', '09/03/2016', '17/03/2016', '18/03/2016', '22/03/2016',
'23/03/2016', '23/03/2016', '30/03/2016', '31/03/2016', '01/04/2016']
```

This could help with data having more variance or unexpected formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract the date in the format you want with out the extra characters.

Based in the page structure I have developed a **scraper** using re to demonstrate how I would do it:

```
import requests, re
from lxml import etree


def get_speeach_data(item):
    title = item.xpath('.//h2[@class="tileHeadline"]/a/text()')[0]
    
    sidebar = item.xpath('./span[@class="documentByLine"]')[0]
    sidebar_html = etree.tostring( sidebar )
    
    m = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', sidebar_html)
    date = m.group(1)
    
    m = re.search(r'(\d+h\d+)', sidebar_html)
    hour = m.group(1)
    
    return { 'title' : title, 'date' : date, 'hour' : hour }
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://www2.planalto.gov.br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos/discursos-da-presidenta?b_start:int=0'
    
    r = requests.get( url )
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        page = etree.HTML( r.content )
        
        raw_speeaches = page.xpath('//*[@id="content-core"]/div')
        speeaches = map(get_speeach_data, raw_speeaches)
        print speeaches
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help